# How to display the username after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have to learn C# MVC using `LINQ`. Now I don't know how to send the username after login

How to send the username from the database to view?

```
public ActionResult Login(Login log)
{
    using (var dbs = new guruEntities())
    {
        var check = dbs.Logins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == log.Name && x.Password == log.Password);
        if (check != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.msg = "Wrong data";
        }
    }
    return View("Login");
}

public ActionResult Success(Login log)
{
    using (var dbs = new guruEntities())
    {
        var check = dbs.Logins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == log.Name && x.Password == log.Password);

        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div> 
    Welcome <!--How do I display the Username here? -->
</div>
```

Comment: you can save the username in session and use it later any where in your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use redirect so need use `TempData` to keep your username like this.

```
 public ActionResult Login(Login log)
    {
        using (var dbs = new guruEntities())
        {
            var check = dbs.Logins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == log.Name && x.Password == log.Password);
            if (check != null)
            {
                TempData["UserName"] = check.Name;
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.msg = "Wrong data";
            }
        }
        return View("Login");
    }
```

In your view

```
<div> 
    Welcome @TempData["UserName"]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value in **ViewBag**, **ViewData** or **TempData** object and display on the view same like Session object.

In your case, I think TempData will be good because you are redirecting from 1 ActionMethod to another ActionMethod so.

Please check this link how you can use TempData [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You have a view (the success page), so you should have a ViewModel for properties on that page:

```
public class SuccessViewModel 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Success(Login log)
{
    using (var dbs = new guruEntities())
    {
    var check = dbs.Logins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == log.Name && x.Password == log.Password);

        var vm = new SuccessViewModel { Name = log.Name };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@Model SuccessViewModel
<div> 
    Welcome @model.Name 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the your check is successful add the username to a session then use than session to display the contents on the front-end. My syntax might be a bit wrong but should give you an idea.

```
if (check != null)
{
    Session.Add("Username", check.Name);
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Front-end

```
<div> 
    Welcome @Session["Username"]
</div>
```

I'm suggesting using a session because you can set it once and then use it several times and not just for one redirect.